# Why doesn't member function signature have same specification as function signature?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Why does this work:

```
template <typename F>
struct getFnInfo;

template <typename RT, typename PT>
struct getFnInfo<RT(PT)>
{
    typedef RT R;
    typedef PT P;
};
```

But this doesn't:

```
template <typename CT, typename RT, typename PT>
struct getFnInfo<RT (CT::)(PT)>
{
    typedef CT C;
    typedef RT R;
    typedef PT P;
};
```

Do I just have the syntax wrong?

Note: this is used to extract type information like so:

```
int fn(double);
getFnInfo<decltype(fn)>::R // return type
getFnInfo<decltype(fn)>::P // parameter type
```

I know that there are other ways of doing this, but I'm curious what is stopping this from working?  Is this just another annoying difference between functions and member functions in C++?

Answer (score 5):

There is a type "function" in C++, but there is no type "member function" or "reference to member function." There is only "pointer to member function."

`RT (CT::)(PT)` is therefore syntactic nonsense. You'd need `RT (CT::*)(PT)`, pointer to member function.

And since there is no "member function" type, there is even no legal way to refer to a member function in isolation. If you have a member function `f` inside a class `C`, then `C::f` by itself is an error again. You need to call it (`something.f()` or `C::f()`) or take its address (`&C::f`).

Comment: So just another annoying difference. >:( WHY?

Comment: @Adrian Perhaps because a function makes sense on its own, but a member function does not?

Comment: I don't see it not making sense.  Why do you say that it doesn't?

Comment: A member function is part of a class, and only make sense when there's an instance of that class. The instance is implictly one of the arguments to the member function.

Comment: @Adrian What can you do with a member function on its own?

Comment: @Angew I find it weird that there are only member function pointers, too. Although member function references would cause syntax problems (how to call one ? `a.foo()` ?), I don't see a reason to disallow formulating the type of a member function. You cant' do much with the type of a free function either.

Comment: @Quentin You *can* declare (but not define) a function using just its type. And you can declare both a reference and a pointer to it.

Comment: @Angew now that you say it, I notice that `void foo(int);` is in fact a variable named `foo` of type `void(int)`. Mind blown.

Comment: @Quentin It's not a variable. It's a declaration of a function. C-ish as it is, it's basically for [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05df0a012631120f).

Comment: @Angew syntax-wise, I mean. But maybe I'm pushing it.

Comment: Perhaps you can't declare a member function, but there's really no reason for not creating a reference to one.  `(obj.*memFnPtr)()` vs maybe `(objPtr..memFnRef)()` (could have been the syntax).  I find the non-symmetrical syntax between member functions and functions quite annoying.

Comment: You can even declare a member using a function type: [`using void_f = void();  struct toy { void_f bob; }; void toy::bob() { std::cout << "hello bob\n"; } };`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9877d029dcf117a3)